# Pass ajax response as variable to view laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I'm new in Ajax. I'm trying to pass ajax data as variable to view, but it shows "undefined variable" error.

Here is my functions in controller:

```
public function anything(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->modalId;
    $single_menu = Menu::find($id);
    $decodedMenu = json_decode($single_menu);

    $modal_name = $decodedMenu->name;
    $modal_desctiption = $decodedMenu->description;
    dump($modal_desctiption);
}

public function menu(Request $request)
{
    $category = Category::orderBy('name')->get();

    // SEARCH
    $search = \Request::get('search');

    $menu = Menu::orderBy('name');

    if ($search) {
        $menu = $menu->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
    }

    $menu = $menu->paginate(12);

    return view('programs.menu', compact('menu', 'category', 'search'));
}
```

My menu view:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $(".modal-show-menu").click(function () {
            var modalId = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'menu/' + modalId,
                method: "get",
                data: {'modalId': modalId},
                success: data => {
                    $('#myModal').html(data)
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

@section('content')
    <section class="banner banner-image menu-page-banner">
        <div class="bannerwrap">
            <figure><img src="{{ Config::get('settings.menu_background') }}" alt="Menu page banner"/></figure>
            <div class="banner-text text-center">
                <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>{{ __('programs.menu.title') }}</strong></h1>
                <p class="text-sp ">{{ __('programs.menu.subtitle') }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <main>
        <section class="block menu-page-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    @include('sections.menu.sidebar')

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                        <div class="row menu-listing-wrap gd-view">
                            @foreach($menu as $single_menu)
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 menu-item wow fadeInLeft">
                                    <div class="text-center menu-item-wrap">
                                        <figure><a href="#">
                                                <img class="img-responsive"
                                                     src="{{ $single_menu->image }}"
                                                     alt="Menu image"></a></figure>

                                        <div class="content mar-top">
                                            <h1>{{ $single_menu->id }}</h1>
                                            <h4><a href="#">{{ $single_menu->name }}</a></h4>
                                            <span>{{ $single_menu->subtitle }}</span>
                                            <div class="bottom">
                                                <div class="facts-table">
                                                    <table>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><span>{{ __('programs.menu.calories') }}</span></td>
                                                            <td><span>{{ $single_menu->calories }}gr</span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><span>{{ __('programs.menu.proteins') }}</span></td>
                                                            <td><span>{{ $single_menu->proteins }}gr</span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><span>{{ __('programs.menu.fats') }}</span></td>
                                                            <td><span>{{ $single_menu->fats }}gr</span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><span>{{ __('programs.menu.carbohydrates') }}</span></td>
                                                            <td><span>{{ $single_menu->carbs }}gr</span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                <a id="{{ $single_menu->id }}"
                                                   href="{{ route('anything',$single_menu->id) }}"
                                                   class="modal-show-menu btn" data-toggle="modal"
                                                   data-target="#myModal">{{ __('programs.menu.more') }}</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center menu-pegination wow fadeInUp">
                                {{ $menu->links() }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    @include('sections.menu.modal')
@endsection
```

My modal view:

```
<div class="modal fade menu-pop-up" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://madang_h1.kenzap.com/images/menu-popup.png" alt="Menu image">
            </figure>
            <!--inner starts-->
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 top text-sp">
                            <h3 class="modal-name">{{ $single_menu->name }}
                                <span class="modal-subtitle"> {{ $single_menu->subtitle }} </span>
                            </h3>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                        <hr>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 content">
                        <p>{{ $single_menu->description }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ingredients">
                        <h6>INGREDIENTS</h6>
                        <ul>
                            <li>{{ $single_menu->ingredients }}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <h6>NUTRITION FACTS</h6>

                        <div class="facts-table">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>Calories</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{ $single_menu->calories }}</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>Proteins</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{ $single_menu->proteins }}g</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>Fats</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{ $single_menu->fats }}g</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>Carbohydrates</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{ $single_menu->carbs }}g</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my route:

```
 Route::get('menu', 'ProgramsController@menu')->name('menu');
 Route::get('menu/{id}', 'ProgramsController@anything')->name('anything');
```

My problem is when i dump it, it shows all data ,  but when I'm trying to pass it as variable to modal view ,like $modal_name, $modal_description or $decodedMenu->name , it returns and error as i mentioned before. My question is it any more simple way to make modal dynamically load data, and if i do something wrong? Thanks everyone for your answer in advance

Answer (score 0):

execute{{ $menu }} in blade file, you get any data

Comment: I need to pass data from  this $decodedMenu = json_decode($single_menu);  to my modal

Answer (score 0):

move to `@section('content')` in script or new footer session create and added

```
   @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $(".modal-show-menu").click(function () {
            var modalId = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'menu/' + modalId,
                method: "get",
                data: {'modalId': modalId},
                success: data => {
                    $('#myModal').html(data)
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<section class="banner banner-image menu-page-banner">
    <div class="bannerwrap">
        <figure><img src="{{ Config::get('settings.menu_background') }}" alt="Menu page banner"/></figure>
        <div class="banner-text text-center">
            <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>{{ __('programs.menu.title') }}</strong></h1>
            <p class="text-sp ">{{ __('programs.menu.subtitle') }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I moved scripts to the content part, but it didn't help

Comment: script tag added in after bootstrap popup model